# How do I specify custom wording in a will_paginate view helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate 2.3.25 with Rails 2.3.11.

I'd like my `page_entries_info` view helper to say "Displaying all n [my own custom wording]s" instead of auto-generating the item name based on the model.

What is the syntax to make it do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your translation yaml file to include what you want to call that model when it is being paginated.

After reading this documentation:  https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    models:
      line_item:
        zero:  line items
        one:   line item
        few:   line items
        other: line items
```

Or for a "just this once solution" you can use `page_entries_info`

From the RDoc:

```
page_entries_info(collection, options = {})
```

Renders a helpful message with numbers of displayed vs. total entries. You can use this as a blueprint for your own, similar helpers.

```
  <%= page_entries_info @posts %>
  #-> Displaying posts 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

By default, the message will use the humanized class name of objects in collection: for instance, "project types" for ProjectType models. Override this with the :entry_name parameter:

```
  <%= page_entries_info @posts, :entry_name => 'item' %>
  #-> Displaying items 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:entry_name` parameter.

```
= page_entries_info @posts, :entry_name => 'item'
#-> Displaying items 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

Comment: This is now `:model`, e.g. `model: 'item'`