# How can I overwrite will_paginate page_entries_info method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem with the display of the text messages from `page_entries_info` method. I want to change text in that.

Any Idea?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757726/give-custom-messages-in-page-entries-info-of-will-paginate-in-rails?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @LHH Thanks Its working..